# Open modal on page load - RoR and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a link inside a form that opens a modal:

```
<% if action_name == "new" %>
  <div>
     <%= link_to 'Open Modal', search_samples_samples_path, {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I want to do now is, when the form opens/loads, open the modal directly, without having to click the link.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: you can do it by jquery/javascript. Assing a class to the link and hide it (if you require). Whenever page loads.. `$(document).ready` in jquery, using the class of link, load it on page load. Am i clear ?

Comment: How can I load the link?

Comment: [read the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals): `$("#modal-window").modal("show")`

Comment: try with this `$(".yourButtonClassName").trigger("click");` and let me know whether its working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, it worked with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 document.getElementById('pcrmodal').click();
});
```

And I added the "id" part to the link element, and hide it also (with display:none):

```
<%= link_to 'PCR Anterior?', search_samples_samples_path, {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window', 'id' => 'pcrmodal', 'style' => 'display:none'}  %>
```

Thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use .modal() function provided by bootstrap if you are using that

```
$("#modal-window").modal()
```